# Login Log - MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

This is one MVC application and we are using FormsAuthentication

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, model.RememberMe);
```

We would to maintain log of the users who are accessing the system (For analysis how often one user is accessing the system)

We can catch it while authorizing them through the login page. But as application provides “Remember Me” option which remember the password so in-case one user press it today and access the system tomorrow again we won’t capture.
There are some alternatives which we are thinking (Except removing remember me) but I wonder is there any best way for it?

We just to need to capture day wise data. Like User A last time access on date?

Best Regards.

Comment: You may want to consider a different metric to track the usage.  Logins can be misleading, even if you disable "Remember me".  What if the user leaves to have some coffee and his session expires?  Is this a separate login?  If he logs in and spends two hours, does it count as the same usage as log in and log out?  Page hits provide much better data and you can track them by HttpModule, Http filter as described by ramiramilu or by overriding Authorize attribute for your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

A better place to log authenticate requests is either in a Httpmodule or ActionFilter in ASP.Net MVC. You can get User information from the HttpContent.User and also his cookies information from HttpContext.Request.Cookies

In the following example, even though the user checks the remember me, this HttpModule will invoke and checks for HttpContext. This is a good place to keep track of returning users - [ASP.Net HttpModule for Security](http://cephas.net/blog/2003/09/25/aspnet-httpmodule-security-example/)

The similar feature can be achieved using ActionFilters which is specific to MVC - [Authentication using ActionFilter](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/28/asp_net-authentication-filters.aspx)